# Nginx reverse proxy to Apache with DirectorySlash directive

Tags: apache, nginx

I need to reverse proxy to an `Apache` server running on the localhost. The problem is that Apache redirects requests to directories without a trailing forward slash, to the directory with a trailing forward slash, as part of its `DirectoryRewrite` directive. The below nginx setup works fine when you go to https://myhost/sw/myapp/ but if you forget the trailing forward slash you end up being redirected to http://myhost:8080/sw/myapp. Short of disabling the `Apache DirectoryRewrite` directive what can I do to make sure that the `/` is always added to the end of any request so that Apache does not redirect?

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 10240M;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name  "";

    ssl_certificate      ../ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ../ssl/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location /sw {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/sw;
        proxy_redirect ~^http://127.0.0.1:8080/sw/([^.]*[^/])$ https://$host/sw/$1/;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ https://$host/;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        HOST            $host;
        proxy_set_header        Referer         $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        error_page 301 302 303 = @handle_redirect;
    }
```

Comment: If Apache is redirecting to `http://myhost:8080/`, you probably need a `proxy_redirect http://myhost:8080/ https://myhost/;`. If you use `curl -I` you can see the exact text of the `Location:` header in the 3xx response.

Comment: I did exactly that and it worked. In the end I replaced `myhost` with `$host` incase myhost ever changes. Please post your response as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the upstream server is redirecting to `http://example.com:8080/` (rather than `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`) you will need to change or add another `proxy_redirect` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

For example:

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com:8080/ https://example.com/;
```

Or as you stated in comments:

```
proxy_redirect http://$host:8080/ https://$host/;
```

The `proxy_redirect` values need to exactly match the beginning of the `Location:` header in the 3xx response. You can use `curl -I` to identify the exact contents of that response header.