# Nginx handle two steps 301/302

Tags: nginx

I have read [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/641070/nginx-302-redirect-resolve-internally) but it seems like it doesn't work for my case.

My case:
Nginx is listening to 443 and forward all request to backend 8080 port.

```
server {
      server_name  abc.public.com;
      location /App {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/App;
      }
 }
```

However, backend has two step of redirect:

step1: redirect from /App to /App/Home, Nginx can handle this without issue

step2: redirect from /App/Home to /App/NewHome/index.jsp

it's expected this one to be: `https://abc.public.com/App/NewHome/index.jsp`
but it becomes: `http://abc.public.com/App/NewHome/index.jsp`

since port 80 is disabled on firewall, therefore client browser is stuck there, configuration like: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` wouldn't work in this case.

is there any better idea to handle this two steps 301/302?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353485/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-apache-with-directoryslash-directive/54355059#54355059).